# How can I detect double click on brush object?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying add double click event on d3 brush object.
But I am not quite sure how can I do that.

I tried to add .on("dblclick", functionName) in the brush object like this:

```
MyGroup.append("g")
             .attr("class", "viewWindow")
             .call(viewPort)
             .selectAll("rect")
             .style("fill", "#fff3b7")
             .style("fill-opacity", 0.5)
             .attr("height", miniHeight)
             .attr("id", "viewWindow")
             .on("dblclick", brushExpand);
```

However, its not working. The double click event is not triggering.
How can I add a doubleclik event in a brush object?

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle the above scriptlet seems to be OK..

Comment: Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pixelord/72ncbc7q/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of attaching doubleclick like this on `#viewWindow`:

```
.attr("id", "viewWindow")
.on("dblclick", function() { 
     d3.select("#viewWindow").attr("fill", "red")
 });
```

Seems like the doubleclick does not work, I believe d3 is overriding the double click *(That is reason why we are not getting event)*.
So I am using another approach to capture double click.

```
//declare variable
var click = false;
d3.selectAll("#viewWindow").on("mousedown", function() {
  if(click){//if true then double click
    console.log("double click");
    //do what you want to do in double click
    d3.selectAll("#viewWindow").attr("fill", "red");
    //set flag to false
    click=false;
  } else {
    //timeout to reset the flag after 500 milliseconds of 1st mouse down.
    setTimeout(function(){click=false;}, 500);
  }
  click = !click;
})
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/bbv0n18o/)

Hope this helps!